# I have two PCs on the same router with drastically different speeds

Tags: networking, router

I upgraded to a DOCSIS 3.1 modem. This goes into a Gig speed router with 4 ports.

One port is hard-wired to a Dell Optiplex 3050 and speed tests come in around 800 Mbps.

Another PC (Toshiba Portege laptop) is hard-wired to the same router and speed tests come in around 50Mbps. (Note - the Toshiba was originally a Windows 7 PC that was upgraded to Windows 10.)

My wireless network is disabled.

What is going on? Thanks.

Comment: See if there is a better Windows 10 LAN driver for the laptop. That is the first thing to try because the issue is restricted to the laptop.  I assume you tried a different Ethernet cable for the laptop.

Comment: My thinking is that Windows keeps updating drivers and the current one is an Intel gigabit driver that looks like it should work. I could try another one but I wouldn't know which one to use. Also, all the troubleshooting and updating programs I've used say I'm good. I'll keep looking for a specific recommendation, but I have the feeling it is something else in the chain that doesn't support gig speeds. It's like I'm running on a 100 mbps limit. I was thinking of trying a USB adapter and seeing if it might bypass the bottleneck.  Thanks for the assist. JMcG

Comment: You can look in Device Manager and see (under Networks) what Wi-Fi card you have and update the driver from that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you replace the cable on the slow machine. Kinks and sharp bends in cable can restrict speed. as explained at https://www.anixter.com/en_us/resources/literature/wire-wisdom/minimum-bend-radius.html

Comment: Thanks. Didn't help but needed to do it.